# How to handle events sequentially when using an asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using events to listen to a data change stream https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams

Each event that comes in is handled via an aync `handleChange` function. The first part of the function i do the normal processing of the data and the second part of the function i want to store a `resumeToken`.

This `resumeToken` is important because it allows me to restart my listener incase there is a crash.

However i have a problem - when i am processing each event with an async handler, the resume token in the end that gets stored is the last event that was processed and not emitted. This means the resumeToken may lag behind and when i restart the process, it may resume at point which it has already previously processed.

**The code below is the smallest isolated example of what is happening.**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

let resumeToken; // Stored in external db;

// simulate an update to resumeToken where time taken could be different
const updateResumeToken = async (token) => {
  const randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resumeToken = token;
    resolve();
  }, randomTime));
}

const handleChange = async (data) => {
  console.log("current", data, resumeToken)
  await updateResumeToken(data.value);
  console.log("new", data, resumeToken);
}

myEmitter.on('change', handleChange);

myEmitter.emit('change', {"token": "first", value: 1} );
myEmitter.emit('change', {"token": "second", value: 2});
myEmitter.emit('change', {"token": "third", value: 3});
```

https://replit.com/join/btniqwwkzl-kaykhan

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but you can transform the event emitter into an async iterable and process events sequentially. [`event.on`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html#eventsonemitter-eventname-options) is available from Node.js v12.16

```js
import { EventEmitter, on } from "node:events";

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

let resumeToken;

const updateResumeToken = async (token) => {
  const randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resumeToken = token;
    resolve();
  }, randomTime));
}

setTimeout(() => {
  myEmitter.emit("change", { token: "first", value: 1 });
  myEmitter.emit("change", { token: "second", value: 2 });
  myEmitter.emit("change", { token: "third", value: 3 });
}, 1000);

// Process events sequentially. `updateResumeToken` is awaited before processing next event
for await (const [data] of on(myEmitter, "change")) {
  console.log("current", data, resumeToken);
  await updateResumeToken(data.value);
  console.log("new", data, resumeToken);
}
```

Hope this helps others who stumble upon this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. I get the `data` as an array with the emitted object inside, is that normal?

Comment: Oh yes, `on()` resolves with an array since an event can have more than one value! Thanks for mentioning, I've updated the post. Glad you found it helpful! I actually ended up recording a lesson about this in my new [Practical Async/Await course](https://maximorlov.com/practical-async-await/)